# Missing request parameter with AJAX file upload to Web API

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have been searching for a while in how to upload a file specifically a picture to a web api action. This is my first exposure to single page application. Basically what I am trying is that using knockout I created a custom binding that encodes the file in base 64 and puts it in a view model property.

After that using knockout submit binding I am capturing the form and creating a FormData object and appending the file, I have tried to use Ajax and right now I am trying XMLHTTPRequest object to send the data to the server side.

The problem is that the content of the request is coming empty to the server side, when I see the request sent by the browser (Chrome) the image is being appended to the payload request. Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Thanks.
This is the HTML with the knockout custom binding for the file upload

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-bind="submit: upload">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-default side-btn btn-file">
          <span class="camera-icon no-decoration"></span>
          <input id="fileUpload" type="file" data-bind="file: trial.picture, fileObjectURL: trial.pictureUrl, fileDataUrl: trial.pictureData">
        </span>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled placeholder="Trial picture" value="{{trial.pictureUrl}}">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large center-block" type="submit">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

View Model

```
self.upload = function () {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("picture", self.trial.pictureData);
  trialsService.upload(formData);
}
```

Service that call the web API functionality, I have tried both approaches, the one that is commented and the one using the XMLHttpRequest

```
upload = function (FormData) {
  var url = common.configuration.apiBaseUrl + 'upload/upload-file';
  //return common.wrapDataEvents(http.post, url, form);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("post", url);
  request.send(FormData);

  //$.ajax({
  //    type: "POST",
  //    url: url,
  //    contentType: false,
  //    processData: false,
  //    data: data,
  //    success: function (res) {
  //        //do something with our ressponse
  //        console.log("Uploaded");
  //    }
  //});
};
```

This is the code in the Web API side

```
public void Post()
{
  if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
  {
    var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("c:/uploads/");
    var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
      {
        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
      });

  }
  else
  {
    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
  }
}
```

Request sent by the browser (Chrome)

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8888
Request URL:http://localhost:59704/api/upload/upload-file
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:14
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 03 Apr 2015 12:42:55 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RDpcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRcU2FtQ2xvdWRcU0FNQ2xvdWQuV2ViU2VydmljZVxhcGlcdXBsb2FkXHVwbG9hZC1maWxl?=
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,it;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:808013
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryL75dJpHubJiMYGnC
Host:localhost:59704
Origin:http://localhost:49921
Pragma:no-cache
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://localhost:49921/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryL75dJpHubJiMYGnC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"

---Picture's data encoded in base 64. omitted for brevity
```

Comment: The request log you posted looks good to me, so my first suspect would be a server-side issue — maybe it considers the request parameters in some way malformed and drops them? Can you dump and log all request parameters in your controller method?

Comment: I took the liberty of pushing your question more towards people with ASP.net Web API experience; hopefully you will get better responses this way.